# Capistrano Ruby Security Error

Tags: ruby, debian, capistrano, rbenv

Capistrano is erroring out on this command

```
  * executing "cd -- /home/root/apps/case/releases/20130221234114 && bundle exec 
rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- 
/home/root/apps/case/shared/assets/manifest.yml
/home/root/apps/case/releases/20130221234114/assets_manifest.yml"
```

and I get this response after it

```
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] ruby
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] :
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] no -I allowed while running setgid
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] (
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] SecurityError
** [out :: 108.60.137.195] )
```

Can't seem to find anything related except for a couple of issues with Ruby compiling on macports. I'm using rbenv with Ruby 1.9.3-p385 on Debian 6.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a shared (system-wide) install of rbenv? Old instructions (deleted from wiki as of now, but can be accessed at https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Shared-install-of-rbenv/a86ef2e6b12254eeb7cecfd3bd878cf7382d1b4a) suggests setting SGID permission bit on Ruby interpreter, which triggers security warnings (and with a good reason).

Current rbenv documentation suggests installing a project-local installation (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Deploying-with-rbenv). Alternatively, it could use a system-wide installation without SGID, and using --deployment flag for bundler so that it doesn't try to write to system-wide directories.